# How to rename Chatter Tab?

Tags: lightning-experience, chatter

Is it possible to rename the Chatter tab or create a custom lightning page similar to the chatter page to set the tab name as per our wish? Because, I couldn't find the below-highlighted component in the app builder

I can do that only in communities. But, I need that in internal Lightning Apps. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_rename_chatter_tab.htm&type=0 check the above article.

Comment: I did @Abhishek Mudireddy. It only applies to Communities. Not for internal apps.

Comment: I think it's not possible. An Idea is already raised https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000IhefAAC

Comment: @Abhishek Mudireddy, is there any way to add the above-highlighted component in custom lightning page? I couldn't find that one in the app builder.

Comment: I suspect it's not possible @venkat.